# dot product of arrays with missing second dimension

Tags: python, numpy

Kindly take a look at the code below.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(10)
b = np.random.rand(10)
c = np.dot(a,b)
```

a and b are arrays of dimension (10,). The dot product is however a scalar value.

By following the matrix multiplication rule (mXn * nXp = mXp), I expected an array of dimension (10,). Can you please explain?

Comment: Dot Product is not same as matrix multiplication.

Comment: Read tbe docs for `np.dot`

Comment: See the recent discussion at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54730082/why-does-numpy-dot-product-of-2d-array-with-1d-array-produce-1d-array