# How does numpy dot product works

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Here is a scenario I'm trying to validate and something is bothering in the way numpy works(or atleast misleads me as i'm new to numpy and python)

```
v1 = np.arange(3)

v2 = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)

v1 = [0 1 2]
(3,)

v2 = 

[[0 1 2]
 [3 4 5]    
 [6 7 8]]
(3, 3)

v1.dot(v2)  gives [15 18 21] which looks straight forward
```

Can someone explain how the below statement works and whats the logic behind it?

```
v2.dot(v1) gives [5 14 23]
Atleast if it gives the result as

[[5]

[14]

[13]], that would make sense to me..
```

From all my research and breaking my head, I could only conclude that multiplying a 2D matrix with a 1D matrix would always result in 1D matrix(in this case 3,). Is it true?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54730082/why-does-numpy-dot-product-of-2d-array-with-1d-array-produce-1d-array) give you more insight?

Comment: Did your research include reading the `np.dot` docs?  It explains what happens when one of the arrays is 1d.  You want a (3,1) result.  why?

Comment: If a is an N-D array and b is a 1-D array, it is a sum product over the last axis of a and b. -- Is this the scenario you meant? I did check this already, but it hdidn't help me much to visualize the process. They haven't provided any example for this scenario either at the bottom of the page

And regarding, You want a (3,1) -- No. I was actually researching to understand how dot product works and got this doubt

Comment: Your `vector.dot(matrix)` case falls under the `N-D` with `M-D` case,  Pairing the 'last axis of a' (doesn't matter that is the only axis) with `2nd to the last of b`.  So it's `c[m]=sum(a[:] * b[:,m])`.  An explicit `1-D` with `M-D` case isn't necessary.  The `N-D` with `1-D` needs its own case because `2nd to the last` needs clarification when there's only one axis.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you @hpaulj for the explanation.

Comment: @mabergerx - Thanks for sharing the link. It was really helpful